# How do I query this properly?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my code, I am using my login system to display certain content to certain account levels. The problem is that for some reason my code is not working. As you can see below I am querying:

```
SELECT rank FROM members WHERE username='$authUser'
```

Which is supposed to get the rank of the user that is logged in Via:

```
$_SESSION['username']
```

PHP

```
<?php
include "dbconf.php"; 
include "loginheader.php";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
    //Trying to set PDO error mode to exception I guess?
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //No Need to say if we connected successfully. // echo "Connected Successfully!";
    $authUser = $_SESSION['username']; // get logged in user.
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT rank FROM members WHERE username='$authUser'");
    $userrank = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection to database has failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

function ShowRank($user) {
    echo '<font color="green">' . $userrank[1] . '</font>';
}

?>
```

Now, where I am having trouble is that when I use:

```
var_dump($userrank);
```

What I get is an array that looks like this:

```
 array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["rank"]=> string(13) "Administrator" } }
```

So naturally I wrote:

```
 echo $userrank[1];
```

However, for some reason it is returning empty. The output should be "Administrator" shouldn't it?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @JayBlanchard That still is coming up empty.

Comment: I'd suggest putting some example code here (http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) so people can help you a little bit better.

Comment: I just tested out `echo $userrank[0]['rank']` and it should work for you. Working example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b20c1d17e41718661a4d0e459cdc23272a8221ed

Comment: @BrianMoreno You were correct. It was working but was outside the scope of my function. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd need to use

`echo $userrank[0]->rank`

Alternatively you could return the results as an associative array using

`$userrank = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

and then use

`echo $userrank[0]['rank']`

Comment: Neither of those methods work. The output I get from `echo $userrank[0]['rank']` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can access your array something like this

```
echo $userrank[0]->rank;
```

Comment: The output is empty.

Comment: do a echo '<pre>'; print_r($userrank); paste the output please

Comment: The output is: 
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rank] => Administrator
        )

)`

Comment: @MuhammadUsman He said in a different comment he gets an empty output using that method. "The output I get from echo $userrank[0]['rank'] is empty."

Comment: Output is still EMPTY.

Answer (score 0):

Please use $userrank[0]->key 
 ex: $userrank[0]->rank